# No Directionality widget found. RichText widgets require a Directionality widget ancestor

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am trying to run the simplest possible flutter app by printing **Hello World** in the screen.

Following [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13025), I tried both of the snippets :

```
void main() {
    runApp(
        new Center(
            child: new Text("Hello World!", textDirection: TextDirection.ltr)
        )
     );
}
```

**&&**

```
void main() {
    runApp(new Center(
      child: new Directionality(
          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
          child: new Text('Hello, world!'))));
}
```

But I get error  which says :

> No Directionality widget found. RichText widgets require a Directionality widget ancestor.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me after :

**Full Restart**